# Sending SMS in lua files

Tags: lua, sms, coronasdk

I am trying to send a SMS from a lua script. 
I researched and found the native.showPopup, but I want to send the SMS from the app itself, not composing it!

Can you help me? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url = "sms:1-234-456-6789?body=Hello%2C%20World!"
system.openURL(url)
```

The current system.openURL() docs in Corona Labs doesn't mention "sms" as valid URL type but I've seen this mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. You might be able to do it with Corona native which is free now.